# Multi-page Flex Dashboard plots with incorrect zoom levels

Tags: r, d3.js, knitr, htmlwidgets, flexdashboard

**EDIT** It appears the issue is related to the lack of a 'resize' method in NetworkD3: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/68#issuecomment-228521468

I'm encountering an issue when I create 2 SankeyNetwork plots and wish to display them on separate pages of a Flex Dashboard.

The first plot loads on the first page with no issue - looking exactly as it should.

However, when I flip to the second page, the second SankeyNetwork plot is tremendously zoomed in - making it unreadable. Clicking 'refresh' automatically fixes the plot - bringing it back to it's correct perspective. Then - when I click back to the first page - that plot is zoomed in in the same manner.

It doesn't appear to matter which plot I place on the first or second pages... Is there some sort of caching setting I need to alter?

[image: Zoomed in Plot on 2nd page]

[image: Plot after right clicking and selecting 'Refresh']

**Edit**
Here's example code - created in a FlexDashboard template in RStudio and leveraging the SankeyNetwork example provided by the NetworkD3 creators. In this

````
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---
Page 1
==================
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(networkD3)

URL <- paste0(
        "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
        "master/JSONdata/energy.json")
Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
# Plot
s1<-sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

### Page 1 {data-width=650}

```{r}
  s1

```

Page 2
==================

### Page 2 {data-width=350}

```{r}
s1
```
````

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example of this so that we have a better chance of being able to help?

Comment: Sorry about that - added an example

Comment: Awesome! No worries. It takes long but adding reproducible examples pays off in more / better answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this [pull request](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/pull/133) should partially solve the problem.  Please test and verify.  Unfortunately, the solution requires some tradeoffs.  I tried to discuss those in the pull request, but in general my opinion is that the non-flexdashboard context should prevail, so I have left the `viewBox` resize mechanism in place and will only render if `height` or `width` is 0.  Thanks for the prompting.  Hope this works ok for you.

Here is a [live example](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/4b01bbdea890dea55aca41ad1d2dd950).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is an issue with `flexdashboard` as I am having the same problem. See [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrjoh3/e4f191bd4259a671d19ba7687a862ffb)

update: this is due to htmlwidget `resize` function not being properly implimented. (I'm trying to fix the widget)

Answer (score 0):

when i use a new column and set the size this problem disappears.  i bet this will solve your issue

example:

### Column {data-width=650}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by following the steps described in the top post here:

https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/122#issuecomment-228551872

**comment out the viewBox code in sankeyNetwork.js, and un-comment the resize function code**